# Verification progress decreasing when validating genesis block

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain

I've been experimenting with the litecoin source and have decided to make my own token network for personal use. I've mined my own genesis block, and assigned unique identifiers for base58Prefix and pchMessageStart.

`getblockchainInfo` returns:

```
{ 
   "chain" : "main",
    "blocks" : 0,
    "headers" : 0,
    "bestblockhash" : "00000ee1064237cca4001f4707031d29c0253c09005c67f0ff9fdeb268591c26",
    "difficulty" : 0.00024414,
    "verificationprogress" : 0.00255052,
    "chainwork" : "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010"
}
```

verificationprogress has been steadily decreasing, but according to https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#getblockchaininfo verification progress is supposed to start at 0 and increase to 1, is it validating correctly? If so will I receive the premine reward once the genesis block is fully verified?